# O que é a Camada de Dados (Data Layer)?

Tags: javascript

A maioria dos sites que eu vou se eu uso dataLayer no console, ele me traz algumas informações, já outros não... Por exemplo, aqui no SOpt não traz. Vi também que o Google Tag Manager usa o dataLayer pra fazer muitas coisas.

O que é exatamente isso então e como "criar um" pra algum site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## O que é

A Camada de Dados é um conjunto de informações do website ou do usuário, sendo responsável pela centralização desses dados e permitindo seu uso por diversas ferramentas de Marketing Digital.

## Implementação básica da Camada de Dados

Na prática, a Camada de Dados pode ser um `Objeto` ou uma `Lista JavaScript`, de acordo com o padrão de um `Tag Manager` específico ou conforme melhor se adequar a cada caso. Vamos adotar o padrão do Google Tag Manager para esse exemplo:

Como a `Camada de Dados` será utilizada pelo `Tag Manager`, é preferível que sua declaração esteja antes da chamada do `Tag Manager`, caso contrário, ele não terá acesso aos dados declarados na Camada e não funcionará conforme esperado.

Um exemplo de implementação ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
window.dataLayer = [
{
  "page": 
          {
            "title": "E-commerce Brasil",
            "category": "Home"
          }
}
];
```

## Geral

No geral é bastante utilizada para leitura e implementação de dados, por exemplo um determinado site de compras utiliza esse método para extração de dados do que o usuário visita, com base nisso o site direciona ao "Google ADS" o tipo de produtos quer que os anúncios direcionem o usuário

Exemplo:

-Visitei o site da pichau vi vários produtos amd: [image: kits amd]
-Os anúncios em outros sites começaram a ser direcionados: [image: anuncio]

Isso é feito por meio de DataLayer, também existem outras utilizações mas peguei um exemplo mais nítido para melhor visualização do exemplo.

Recomendo leitura: https://blog.dp6.com.br/o-que-%C3%A9-a-camada-de-dados-ou-data-layer-80f37fa3429c